# How Do I Authenticate OneNote Without Opening Browser?

Tags: python, authentication, terminal, onenote, onenote-api

I want to create a python script that will allow me to upload files to OneNote via command line. I have it working perfectly and it authenticates fine. However, everytime it goes to authenticate, it has to open a browser window. (This is because authentication tokens only last an hour with OneNote, and it has to use a refresh token to get a new one.) While I don't have to interact with the browser window at all, the fact that it needs to open one is problematic because the program has to run exclusively in a terminal environment. (E.g. the OneNote authentication code tries to open a browser, but it can't because there isn't a browser to open).

How can I get around this problem? Please assume it's not possible to change the environment setup.

**UPDATE:**

You have to get a code in order to generate an access token. This is the part that launches the browser. It is only required the first time though, for that initial token. Afterwards, refresh token requests don't need the code. (I was calling it for both, which was the issue).

That solves the problem of the browser opening each time I run my program. However, it still leaves the problem of the browser having to open that initial time. I can't do that in a terminal environment. Is there a way around that?

E.g. Can I save the code and call it later to get the access token (how long until it expires)? Will the code work for any user, or will it only work for me?

Answer (score 0):

If this is always with the same account - you can make the "browser opening and password typing" a one time setup process. Once you've authenticated, you have the "access token" and the "refresh token". You can keep using the access token for ~1hr. Once it expires, you can use the "refresh token" to exchange it for an "access token" without any user interaction. You should always keep the refresh token so you can get new access tokens later.

This is how "background" apps like "IFTTT" keep access to your account for a longer period of time.

Answer to your updated question:

The initial setup **has to be through UI in a browser**. If you want to automate this, you'll have to write some UI automation.

Comment: Yes, and I successfully get and use both the access and refresh token. However, I've found all the refresh token does is save the user from having to manually click their permission (which they had to do the first time), but it still opens a browser window for about half a second and then immediately shuts this again. This isn't a problem for a user, who doesn't have to interact with the window at all, but it is a problem when running the code in an environment that is unable to launch a browser window, because it causes the request to break.

Comment: I have not tried this with python but certainly using CLI php scripts the process of retrieving an acess token using a long lasting "refresh token" works without issue.
@Jorge can correct me, but when you update the "access token" a new long lasting "refresh token" is issued which can be stored for further calls.

Comment: @Elliptica: The call to exchange the refresh token for the is a REST call and requires no user interaction. You are redirecting the user, which is not what I my original answer suggested.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659750.aspx

Comment: @JorgeAguirre You are correct (please see the update I posted to my original question). The issue is not with getting the refresh token, but the initial call to getting an access token the very first time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a browser to refresh the token, that can be done by just a simple http request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-auth#get-new-access-token-msa

Comment: Yes, and I have that implemented, but whenever I make that request, it opens a browser window for about half a second and then immediately closes it. If I try to make a request in an environment without a browser, it breaks.

Comment: Do you have an example request? The refresh token does not depend on cookies, you just need to do POST request as described on the link with the proper authorization field (look for Authorization: Bearer {access-token} on the page).

Comment: The request I'm referring to is the intial authorization request, not the refresh token request. The very first time you go to authorize a OneNote app, it opens a browser window and requires you to physically click "authorize" in order to receive your initial access and refresh token. That is the part I can't figure out how to do on a windowless OS.

Comment: The initial authorization is always done through a browser (the user has to agree to give you access to her data, that is the whole point). From then on you are gonna have an Access Token which you can choose to store, same true for the Refresh Token. But it is better to store them securely. (the IOS sample code stores them in the user's keychain)

All the SDKs/samples use a browser component for authorization: https://dev.onedrive.com/sdks.htm